# How do I count the number of select lists with selected values using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating the mobile version on a current Rails app with a "quiz" feature. There is currently a count of how many questions you have answered being generated by this function.

```
function updateGroupProgressCounter($group){
 var count = $group.find('tr').has('input:checked').length;
 $group.parents('.carousel').find('.checkedCount').text( count);
}
```

I am changing the inputs from radio buttons to select boxes for mobile and want to keep the count feature but can't quite make it work so far. I've tried

```
var count = $group.find('tr').has('select option:selected').length;
```

but gives me the total number of questions in that group. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would toggle a class on the row based on select change event, then count those rows.

```
$('tr select').change(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('answered', $(this).val()!='' );
});
```

Second argument of `toggleClass` determines whether to add/remove.

Then to get total rows:

```
$('tr.answered').length
```

**[toggleClass() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**

Another approach using `filter()` to count `select` that have value

```
var number_answered=$('tr select').filter(function(){
      return $(this).val !='';
}).length
```

Comment: This should do the trick. I am conveniently already toggling the class to insure they have made a selection. I will just tie into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

```
$("#boxes").on("change","input", function(){
    $("#total").val($("#boxes input:checked").length);  
});
```

Play around with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtxG4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the value of first element of your select list is empty(i.e "")

So the code will be

```
var count = 0;
$group.find('tr select').each(function(){
   if(this.value.length)
     count++;
});
```

I know this is not the best way to do it. 
Adding and removing class on the basis of selection and finally finding the length of element that contains required class would be better approach as suggested by @charlietfl.